# Installing UCM 10g through .BAT file

Tags: batch-file, oracle-ucm

I want to install ucm 10g using a .bat file, till now I have made a bat file UCM.BAT which will generate a input.txt as input to Installer.exe of UCM 10g, have a look at my .BAT file.

```
@echo off
>input.txt echo 4
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo D:/stellent/ucm/server
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo d:/stellent/ucm/server/vault/
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo d:/stellent/ucm/server/weblayout/
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo c:/program files/internet explorer/iexplore.exe
>>input.txt echo 4
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 4444
>>input.txt echo 4440
>>input.txt echo 127.0.0.1
>>input.txt echo /idc/
>>input.txt echo mail
>>input.txt echo sysadmin@mail
>>input.txt echo INEDEC-MLAP-645.emrsn.org
>>input.txt echo idc
>>input.txt echo idc
>>input.txt echo Content Server idc
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo localhost
>>input.txt echo 1521
>>input.txt echo stellent_admin
>>input.txt echo stellent_admin
>>input.txt echo xe
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 1,2,3,4,5
>>input.txt echo F
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo 1
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo 2
>>input.txt echo 1


C:\Users\gurlove.chopra\Desktop\ContentServer_Windows_10gR3_20080807  \UCM\ContentServer\win32\Installer.exe input.txt
```

Now Following is the Error I am getting

```
C:\Users\gurlove.chopra\Desktop\ContentServer_Windows_10gR3_20080807\UCM\Content
Server\win32>UCM.BAT
Unable to install. IntradocDir is not defined.
Severe error: wait.dat not removed. Remove manually.
```

Any kind of help is Appreciated

Comment: You may want to consider installing 12c since 10g is now 8+ years old and Extended Support ended in December 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I found that by default, Installer.exe takes input from Intradoc.cfg, which takes input from user turns them to key-value pairs and then feed to Installer.exe.

So now either we can give direct input to Intradoc.cfg or create a input.txt with the necessary key-value pairs.I did it by generating input.txt

here's the solution

```
@echo off
(
echo IdcProductName=idccs
echo IntradocDir=D:/stellent/ucm/server4/
echo ConfigureProxiedServer=no
echo ConfigureAdminServer=yes
echo WebBrowserPath=c:/program files/internet explorer/iexplore.exe
echo InstallType=new
echo InstallConfiguration=Install
echo HttpServerAddress=INEDEC-MLAP-645.emrsn.org
echo SysAdminAddress=sysadmin@mail
echo IntradocServerPort=5555
echo IdcAdminServerPort=5550
echo MailServer=mail
echo IDC_Name=idc4
echo InstanceMenuLabel=idc4
echo InstanceDescription=Content Server idc4
echo WebServer=apache
echo DisableDatabaseOverrides=1
echo DatabaseType=oracle
echo DBServerHost=localhost
echo DBServerPort=1521
echo JdbcUser=stellent_gc4
echo JdbcPassword=stellent_gc4
echo DBServerDatabase=xe
echo ConfigureJdbcDriverPackageSourceFile=false
echo CreateDatabase=true
echo InstallAdminServerService=auto
echo InstallAdminServerServiceConfigureRunAs=false
echo InstallAdminServerServiceUser=
echo InstallAdminServerServicePassword=
echo InstallAdminServerServiceConfigureDependency=false
echo InstallAdminServerServiceDependency=
echo InstallServerService=auto
echo InstallServerServiceConfigureRunAs=false
echo InstallServerServiceUser=
echo InstallServerServicePassword=
echo InstallServerServiceConfigureDependency=false
echo InstallServerServiceDependency=
echo MEDIA_DIR=$BIN_DIR/../../..
echo SHARED_CONFIG_DIR=$BIN_DIR/..
echo OS_DIR=$SHARED_CONFIG_DIR
echo InstallDefinitionFile_cs=cs_install_info.htm
)>input.txt
C:\Users\gurlove.chopra\Desktop\ContentServer_Windows_10gR3_20080807\UCM\ContentServer\win32\Installer.exe input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The input.txt file you are creating in your does not look like it is supposed to. It should be a list of name=value entries.

You have the details in Appendix E in this document: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10316_01/cs/cs_doc_10/documentation/integrator/install_cserver_win_10en.pdf